How to pass a field from a class to an arrow function in decorator?
I would like to use a field from a class in an arrow function passed to a decorator:
export function decorator(nameOrNameFn: string | ((...args: any[]) => string)) {
    return function (value: Function, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext) {
        return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
            const name = typeof nameOrNameFn === 'function' ? nameOrNameFn.apply(this, args) : nameOrNameFn;
            console.log(name);
            value.apply(this, args);
        };
    };
}

class Example {
    readonly field: string;

    constructor(field: string) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @decorator(param => `Logging inside decorator: ${param} + ${this.field}`)
    method(param: string) {
        console.log('Logging inside method: ' + param)
    }
}

new Example('fieldValue').method('paramValue');

This example in TypeScript Playground
I know that I can achieve this by passing a normal function instead:
@decorator(function (t) {
    return `User "${this.email}" receives "${t.mailSubject}" email`;
})

But I would prefer to do this with an arrow function or something similar. Is it possible?

arrow functions don't have a this context so what you're writing is impossible. If you want your arrow function to have another parameter corresponding to this like this playground link shows you could do that. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Yes, I think it may solve my problem, but maybe I was not precise enough. In most cases, when I use this decorator, I don't need to use thiz. I just use parameters from a method.
I presented it in this example. Is it possible to make it work in all cases?

@kosteklvp no, but you can always add a dummy parameter to eat this: example

You could move thiz to the end (as long as your methods aren't variadic) as shown in this playground link. No matter what your choices are either to use a non-arrow function expression to access this, or to refactor your code so that the decorator call gets access to this in some other way. Does this fully address the question now? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I still missing?

@jcalz I think this will be the best solution. You can add this as an answer. A little explanation of what is happening inside @step would be helpful. Thanks.

@jcalz I wanted to add types to this decorator. I have a problem with accurate type for thiz parameter. Can you take a look, why it does not work? https://tsplay.dev/wQQGVw
